# Android SqlCipher library error in openOrCreateDatabase method

Tags: android, sql, sqlcipher

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt databse in my application using `SqlCipher` library, but while doing decryption following exceptions are occurring..Encryption sometimes works fine.

```
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database


CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

Unsatisfied Link error while using `SQLCipher` library

Please help me in this.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are including all native libraries and the `icudt46l.zip` file within the `assets` directory of your application.  There is an article covering the steps for integration available [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android).